# read a JSON File (objects and Array)

Tags: php, arrays, json

im experience a proble tryng to read a json the reply from url is this

```
{"metadata":{"iserror":"false","responsetime":"0.00s"},"results":{"result":[{"Name":"testcampaign","Id":86124,"statuscode":"Success","statusmessage":"Campaign Added Successfully..","URL":"http:\/\/ufa.askyou.co.uk","MaxBid":"1.00","Cap":"None","GeoTargets":"US","BrowserTargets":"ie","UniquesOnly":"true","Schedule":"No Schedule, Free To Run"}]}}
```

I need to read reasults result  status code
i have try this but have not worked :

```
$json = file_get_contents($url . $Params . $Params2);
$obj = json_decode($json, true);
echo $obj['results']['result']['statusmessage'];
```

if I use his function to get all data

```
$obj = json_decode($data, true);

foreach ($json as $key => $value) {
    if (!is_array($value)) {
        echo $key . '=>' . $value . '<br/>';
    } else {
        foreach ($value as $key => $val) {
            echo $key . '=>' . $val . '<br/>';
        }
    }
}
```

they say result `Array`.
How can i read this correct?

Comment: Look at the `results` element of the JSON. It contains a nested array inside the `result` property, but your second `foreach` loop doesn't check `is_array($val)`. Why don't you just use `var_dump()` to see the whole thing, instead of trying to echo them?

Comment: thanks for your help the think is if i use var dump i receive this reply

Comment: array(2) { ["metadata"]=> array(2) { ["iserror"]=> string(5) "false" ["responsetime"]=> string(5) "0.00s" } ["results"]=> array(1) { ["result"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(11) { ["Name"]=> string(12) "testcampaign" ["Id"]=> int(86153) ["statuscode"]=> string(7) "Success" ["statusmessage"]=> string(29) "Campaign Added Successfully.." ["URL"]=> string(31) "http://ufa.askyou.co.uk" ["MaxBid"]=> string(4) "1.00" ["Cap"]=> string(4) "None" ["GeoTargets"]=> string(2) "US" ["BrowserTargets"]=> string(2) "ie"  } } } }

Comment: but the think is.. how can i get a specific Value? i need just status and ID , how can i navigate to the correct field? thanks for your time

Comment: solvedjust added this
echo $obj['results']['result'][0]['statusmessage']; 
and im navigating in the right array.. thansk for your time ..

Comment: @AlejandroSarras Please do not use comments to add details to your question.  Please edit your question to include the var_dump information (formatted as code).  Also, if you solved your own question, please post answer and award it the green tick so the question is seen as resolved.  Alternatively, if the core question is **how do I access a value in my multi-dimensional array?**, then this is very low value question which will probably not be helpful to future readers and should be deleted to reduce low-value questions on SO.